# Universal Retina iOS App - is it possible to only download part of the assets?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

I have a universal iOS app with Retina support.

The iPad HD graphics are about 200MB, while the iPhone HD graphics are about 50MB.

Is there a way to have iPhone users only download 50MB and iPad users only download 200MB?

I'm guessing this functionality is probably not included in the App Store but I'm wondering if there's any well-supported third-party application to solve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including all the images in the app, down load most from the web in the app and save them in the app.

Comment: Yes, of course, but does there exist a third-party solution to that problem?

Comment: It's really fairly simple, just put the images on a server and then download in the background and save to the Documents directory  when the app runs. There is really no need for any code on the server. But you will have to pay for the server.